# Binding Exception with Ninject

Tags: azure, ninject, azure-webjobs

We have a central logging component which I am now trying to use in a WebJob that I am developing. I am basically following [this](https://github.com/ThomVanL/NinjectAzureWebJob) example. My Activator is identical, I have the bindingModule that has my Bind statements in it. One thing I have done differently here is to use the method versions:

```
Kernel.Bind(typeof(IExternalSystemLogger)).To(typeof(ExternalSystemLogger));
```

instead of the generic versions in the example. I currently have constructor injection implemented but I have also set up the parameter injection as per the example. Which ever way I try to do this I end up with the error:

```
Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessage' ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot bind parameter
```

or

a null reference exception (with parameter injection). Further into the error I am told that

> Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding

which is the part that I am finding it difficult to resolve. I have looked at the available method calls on the config object available in WebJob.program but none seems to work. What is it I need to call so that I am correctly resolving my type when I am using a QueueTrigger or BlobTrigger?

Comment: could you provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: @JanMuncinsky Thankyou but no need I have managed to resolve the problem. It was just that I needed to pull the projects in to reference them. The term component threw me I think as I was expecting it to be self contained rather than a reference hunt. Never mind all done now.